# No route matches [GET] "/" Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I have these routes available to me after i configured devise:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
               about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
                root        /                              pages#home
```

Now I am using this in my home.html.erb file:

```
<p> 
<%= link_to 'Sign up now!',  new_user_regsitration_path , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</p>
```

Everytime I run server I get this routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

Please help?

Answer (score 6):

If nothing helps, simply restart your server. I had the same error and couldn't figure out what was going on!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your link on the home_page:

```
new_user_regsitration_path
```

should be:

```
new_user_registration_path
```